# Rank posts by comments added today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two models: posts and comments. I want to rank the posts by the # of comments added today. So far I only have it ranked by the number of comments and am not sure how to add the today part.

Here is the posts controller:

```
@posts = Post.order('posts.comments_count desc')
```

I have tried

```
@posts = Post.order('posts.comments_count desc').where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```

but that returned nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second query is giving you the number of **posts** that have been created today, rather than the number of comments that have been created today.

This should be what you're looking for:

```
@posts = Post.select('posts.*, count(comments.id) as count_comments')
             .joins(:comments)
             .where('comments.created_at >= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
             .group('posts.id')
             .order('count_comments desc')
```

If you'd like to include all posts, including ones that don't have any comments today, then you'll need a `left join`:

```
@posts = Post.select('posts.*, count(comments.id) as count_comments')
             .joins("left join comments on comments.post_id = posts.id and comments.created_at >= '#{Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day}'")
             .group('posts.id')
             .order('count_comments desc')
```

Comment: I tried your second example because thats exactly what i need but it gives me this sqlexception: no such column: comments: SELECT  posts.*, count(comments) as count_comments FROM "posts" left join comments on comments.post_id = posts.id WHERE (comments.created_at >= '2014-04-26 00:00:00.000000') GROUP BY posts.id  ORDER BY count_comments desc

Comment: @user2759575 check my updated answer. I changed `count(comments)` to `count(comments.id)`. Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: I think the problem is that its only showing them if a comment has been posted today whereas if no comments are posted id like to just sort the posts by time created.

Comment: @user2759575 Sorry for the delay, but I think my updated answer should work for you. I've move the where clause into the join. If you're not using Postgres then the syntax of `comments.created_at >= '#{Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day}'` may need to be changed up a bit.